# Given finite sets $A$ and $B$, let $I = \{f: A \rightarrow B : f$ is one to one$\}$ and $S = \{f : A \rightarrow B : f$ is onto$\}$. Compute |I||S|.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Maybe I'm overthinking this question. $A$ and $B$ are said to be finite, but how can I express the number of one to one functions and onto functions generically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the relative sizes of the finite sets $A$ and $B$.

**Hints:**

1. If $|A| > |B|$, what can you conclude about $|I|$?
2. If $|A| < |B|$, what can you conclude about $|S|$?
3. If $|A| = |B|$, then an injective function is also a surjective function.  Likewise, every surjective function is also an injective function.  How many injective functions are there from a set with cardinality $n$ to a set with cardinality $n$?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've figured it out.

Let $a = |A|$ and $b = |B|$.

If $a > b$, $|I| = 0$.
If $a < b$, $|S| = 0$.

In either of these cases, $|I| * |S| = 0.$

This leaves the case that $a = b$. Since we want the product of the injectives and surjectives, we have the following:

$|I||S| = P(b, a)\sum_{j=0}^b (-1)^j {b \choose j} (b-j)^a$

However, we can simplify this by acknowledging the fact that $a = b$.

$P(a, b) = P(a, a) = a!$

Since $a = b$, there are also $a!$ bijections. Since there are $a!$ bijections, there has to be $a!$ surjections as well.

$|I||S| = P(b, a)\sum_{j=0}^b (-1)^j {b \choose j} (b-j)^a = a! * a! = (a!)^2$

Comment: Your first two answers are correct.  However, in the third case, you found the number of injective functions, not the product of the number of injective functions and surjective functions.  By the way, injective means one-to-one, while surjective means onto, hence the names of the sets.

Comment: a! was the number of bijective functions, right? Not injective. I've edited my answer, however. Thanks for that catch. Am I correct now?

Comment: Technically, yes, but you can simplify it to an actual number.  As I said in my hint, how many injective functions are there from a set with cardinality $a$ to a set with cardinality $a$?  Also, notice that every injective function from a set with cardinality $a$ to a set with cardinality $a$ is also a surjection and vice versa.  Thus, you should be counting bijections.

Comment: So there are $P(a, a) = a!$ injectives. Since $a = b$, there are also $a!$ bijections, which means there are also $a!$ surjectives. Thus the answer is $(a!)^2$?

Comment: Absolutely!${}$

Comment: I've edited my answer to its complete form. Thank you for the help!